# Community Wiki answers

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Some times I find answers and/or questions with a `community wiki` as an author like in this question [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)
what does this mean? who and how wrote those questions/answers? and who get all those up votes reputations? also there are some revisions information see the screen shot:

[image]

#### Can  any body explain me the element in the red rectangle ?

Comment: I don't usually resort to "let me google that for you", but try [Googling stackoverflow community wiki](https://www.google.ca/search?q=stackoverflow+community+wiki&aq=f&oq=stackoverflow+community+wiki&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l3j62l2.2847&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Here, and on the rest of the Stack Exchange network, it's expected that you'll do at least *some* research before asking a question.